# Android: Revision 21 not appearing in SDK Manager

Tags: android, sdk

Google has released their SDK Revision 21 but it does not appear in my SDK Manager. Here is a snapshot of the SDK Manager:

[SDK Manager](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B0D1yTysOEPPRUNZTThhMHM1Nm8)

Any suggestions as to why?

Comment: Furthermore Eclipse ADT were updated, too and now they are complaining that the SDK revision 21 is required.

Comment: So I need to first update my ADT to see the new revision in SDK Manager?

Comment: No, it is only complaining about it but the SDK Manager does not find it without performing a manual "Reload" as described by "Android Apple".

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Open Android SDK Manager and Packages -> Reload. It works.

Comment: Works indeed - the entries are now shown an can be selected manually.

Comment: @AndroidDev So need to update your ADT plugin first, as Robert said.
Goto Help->Check for Updates on eclipse

Comment: I explicitly asked above whether I needed to update the ADT plugin. Robert wrote "No".

Comment: @AndroidDev He may thought you updated your ADT plugin recently. But your totally out of date, because Clear Cache" under Tools > Options is include before 18

Comment: Found this on the developer site: "To download the new Android 4.0.x system components from the Android SDK Manager, you must first update the SDK tools to revision 20 or later and restart the Android SDK Manager. If you do not, the Android 4.1 system components will not be available for download."

Comment: Same problem here in Ubuntu. I intended to downgrade to ADT 20. Thank God I've seen your answer.

Comment: To see latest versions you need 1st update to latest SDK Tools

Answer (score 5):

Try Tools > Options > Clear Cache, then Packages > Reload, all from the SDK Manager window.

Comment: There is no "Clear Cache" under Tools > Options. Maybe that was a feature added in a later version.

Comment: @AndroidDev: Possibly. I forget when the Clear Cache button was added.

Answer (score 2):

Funny enough, every time I open the SDK manager, it loads a lot of files, but seems not to "reload packages". As far as I can remember, I haven't used the menu entry Packages/Reload for years, but updates always have shown.

It's now the first time I have to do this manually. There is clearly something quite wrong.